# Cocoapods: Two Apps with a shared private Framework, in a WorkSpace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have one workspace that have 2 project and 1 common shared framework, each project can use common framework and on [Two Apps with a shared private Framework, in a WorkSpace](http://netsplit.com/xcode-two-apps-with-a-shared-private-framework-in-a-workspace) but when I added Podfile and execute pod install I got this warning

> [!] The Podfile contains framework or static library targets, for which the Podfile does not contain host targets (targets which embed the framework).
>   If this project is for doing framework development, you can ignore this message. Otherwise, add a target to the Podfile that embeds these frameworks to make this message go away (e.g. a test target).

and I got this error when running my project application

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>     Referenced from: /Users/alfian0/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPMI-arflaxzmdqswkjgsqghdmfizsjws/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Common.framework/Common
>     Reason: image not found

this is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'SIPMI'

project 'Common/Common.xcodeproj'
project 'TKIApp/TKIApp.xcodeproj'
project 'WalletApp/WalletApp.xcodeproj'

def networking_pods
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift', '10.0.2'
end

def application_pods
  pod 'RxCocoa', '4.1.2'
  pod 'Fabric', '1.7.3'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '3.10.0'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '5.0.7'
end

target 'Common' do
  project 'Common/Common.xcodeproj'
  networking_pods
end

target 'TKIApp' do
  project 'TKIApp/TKIApp.xcodeproj'
  application_pods
end

target 'WalletApp' do
  project 'WalletApp/WalletApp.xcodeproj'
  application_pods
end
```

and this is my project structure

[image]